# How can I store data in the hive database in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-hive

I am trying to store a data in the hive database in the flutter application.
I have a recipeID as key and a recipe list which includes recipe name, recipe description etc as a value. Below is my code please go through it where I am making a mistake as I am using hive for the first time. Please tell me how can I resolve the issue.

```
  Future<List> getRecipeDataList() async {
    Box recipeBox = Hive.box("recipes");
    List recipes = [];
    int count = await getRecipeCount();
    int recipeID = 101;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++, recipeID++) {
      if (await checkIfRecipeDocExists(recipeID.toString()) == true) {
        QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> recipesSnapshot =
            await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('recipes').get();
        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> doc
            in recipesSnapshot.docs) {
          final data = doc.data();
          var recipe = Recipes(
            recipeID: doc.id,
            recipeName: data['recipe_name'],
            recipeDescription: data['recipe_description'],
            recipeURL: data['recipeImageURL'],
            recipeRating: data['recipe_rating'],
            recipeTime: data['recipe_time'],
            recipeIngredients:
                (data['recipe_ingredients'] as List<dynamic>).cast<String>(),
          );
          recipeBox.put(doc.id, recipe);
          recipes.add(recipe);
        }
      }
    }
    return recipes;
  }
```

I appreciate all the input in this question. Thankyou.

Comment: If possible use Isar Database instead of Hive. Details is here. https://isar.dev/faq.html#isar-vs-hive

Comment: Did you register the Hive instance in main?

Comment: `Directory document = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();`
`Hive.init(document.path);`
`await Hive.openBox('recipes');`
I had wrote just these three lines to initialize and open the box